# How can i set msg.sender inside foundry script to account from encrypted keystore?

Tags: cloud-foundry, keystore, brownie

i am new in foundry (just moving from brownie) so face the problem of change deployer account in deploy script.  Of course i have read the docs but maybe something passed me by.

Foundry script cli has option:

```
forge script script/CheckKey.s.sol:CheckKey  --account myDeployer --broadcast
```

where `myDeployer` is file name standard keystore file from `~/.foundry/keystores/`.

And here is script example:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.21;

import {Script, console2} from "forge-std/Script.sol";
import "../lib/forge-std/src/StdJson.sol";

contract CheckKeyExample is Script {
    using stdJson for string;

    function run() public {
        vm.startBroadcast();
        console2.log(msg.sender);
        address payable geteth = payable(address(this));
        geteth.transfer(1);
        vm.stopBroadcast();
    }
}
```

what i need to write in my deploy script for change msg.sender (hence account for vm.startBroadcast) to myDeployer address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the terminal, try using below code:

```bash
forge script script/CheckKey.s.sol:CheckKey  --account myDeployer --sender myDeployerPublicAddress --broadcast
```

Also try including RPC URL if you are using any live testnet or mainnet.

Comment: Thank you !  It is really works for me. Yes may be not very convenient to type address (although it can be obtained from keystorage)